# Angular2 hiding output if empty

Tags: angular

I have the code as shown bellow that gets some data from a REST endpoint and displays it in a list. The page loads fine and when input is entered into the textbox everything works as planned. the issue is if a user removes all input from the text box the output the output remains. is there anyway to use ngIf to say if searchRes is is empty then don't show anything? I tried to use `*ngIf="searchRes.length > 0` but there was no change, the old output still got diplayed...

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">&gt;&gt;</span>
      <input type="text"
             class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchStr" name="searchStr" (keyup)="searchWord()">
      <span class="input-group-btn"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="searchRes" class="search-res well">
<div *ngFor="let res of searchRes">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p>{{res}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That should work depending on what the value of `searchRes` is and at what time it has which value (constructor, ngOnInit, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when user removes all input from the text box just make searchRes empty in the component ( if you have other textboxes other than searchStr)

```
searchRes=[];
```

and in the html use

```
<div *ngIf="searchRes && searchStr" class="search-res well">
```

and your code will work fine

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide div with class `search-res well` when there is no value in text box then you can use `<div *ngIf="searchStr" class="search-res well">` or you can make `searchRes = []` in your component `searchWord` method by checking `searchStr` value is empty or not.